# How to represent currency values using java BigDecimal type

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
public class Product {
    private DoubleProperty unitPrice;  

    public Product() {
        this.unitPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    }

        public double getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty unitPriceProperty() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice.set(unitPrice);
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(float unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice.set(unitPrice);
    }
}
```

I want to use the `BigDecimal` type for the model class. What are the lines I should replace to do that? And how should I change the constructor for the `BigDecimal` item?

Comment: Have you tried something which did not work?

Comment: You want to replace Double by Bigdecimal ?

Comment: Assuming that you're doing this for accuracy reasons, you'd be much better using a long and storing the full decimal value in a whole number. You *can* use BigDecimal and still retain accuracy, but it's generally going to be more complex.

Comment: Perhaps find a framework specialized in handling currency types? http://www.baeldung.com/java-money-and-currency or http://javamoney.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Product {
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> unitPrice;  

    public Product() {
        this.unitPrice = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>();
    }

    public BigDecimal getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>unitPriceProperty() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(String unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice.set(new BigDecimal(unitPrice));
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice.set(unitPrice);
    }
}
```

The above more or less corresponds to the double-version. Never use BigDecimal constructors with float or double as argument, as those are imprecise numbers without precision; `new BigDecimal("3.10")` has a scale (precision) of 2.